# Encoding for symbol ¼ ⅝ ⅜ for clob oracle

Tags: oracle, encoding, soa, clob, utf

I need to load from txt file(utf8) to CLOB field in Oracle DB text with symbols like ¼ ⅝ ⅜. 
I do it using ESB project in Soa Suite 10. 
After loadin I get symbols "? ? ?" in clob field.
What can I do to get ¼ ⅝ ⅜ in clob fields?

Comment: It is a display issue with your client. Does your client support the characterset that your are trying to display? To confirm, do the following : `SPOOL the output to a HTML file and open with a browser, you should be able to see proper output, since most of the browsers support multiple charactersets. This will confirm that the issue is with the display of your client`.

Comment: No, in html also see ? ? ?

Comment: Then your **database characterset** doesn't support them.

Comment: What are your database and national [character sets](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/ch2charset.htm#NLSPG164)?

Comment: See [**Why are junk values/special characters/question marks displayed on my client?**](http://lalitkumarb.com/2014/09/24/why-are-junk-values-displayed-in-my-client/).